# How to restrict firebase storage files only for the paid user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have the file stored in firebase cloud storage. This file will only available for the paid user download.

How to set up security rules to allow the paid user to have read access to that file?

[Updated]

I use the cloud firestore to store user collection
Each user doc contain

- uid
- email
- name
- photoUrl
- provider
- status
- stripeCustomerId
- purchasedProducts << this is the array of product name

I can verify paid user by looking if the product exist in purchasedProducts array.

However, inside the security rule from Firebase storage, it seem I can't  access resource (user collection) in there. Or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried that doesn't work the way you expect.  You should also explain what it means for a user to be "paid".  How do you represent this in your system?  There are potentially a lot of moving parts here that need to be understood.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access Cloud Firestore from within the security rules for Firebase Storage.

That means the only ways to currently implement your use-case is to:

- include the necessary information in the ID token of the user, as a custom claim, which is then also [available in security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#properties).
- include the necessary information about the user (probably their UID) in your security rules

Since the second approach requires that you update your rules for every paying user, it's not very common.

Setting a custom claim can be done through the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk), for example from a Cloud Function that triggers when you write their payment information to Cloud Firestore.

Once you set the custom claim it may take up to an hour before it's available on the client, and from there in the security rules. The reason for that is that the claims are included in the ID token, which only auth-refreshes once an hour. If you want to [get the updated claims sooner](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk), you can force a refresh of the user's profile on the client.

Comment: Thanks, Frank, I own you a beer. You saved me not banging my head to the wall. Didn't Firebase Auth can attach a custom claim without implement custom authentication. 

Answer (score 0):

You can access cloud firestore through the firestorage service security rules:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/rules-conditions#enhance_with_firestore